# ContentValues put value as sql-condition

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

When I try to put some condition value into ContentValues variable, there is inserting as String.

```
contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("DLM", "julianday('now', 'localtime')");
```

After executing

```
count = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, selection, selectionArgs);
```

the field is updated but the value is incorrect. I need to have the numeric date in the field, not string.

Another problem if I need to update existing field with the calculated value:

```
UPDATE tbl SET field=field*2
```

When I put the value like

```
contentValues.put("field", "field*2");
```

It has put the value as String. How I can get the value I really needed?

Comment: Just put the numeric value you want, now you're the one causing it to be a String with the " " quotes.

Comment: what's the numeric value for julianday('now','localtime')? I know that there is possible to convert into numeric but this is not optimal for me

Comment: that's the method you've create yourself I guess? Make it return the String you need then, but I would have created a calendar, set the specific date and time of that day, then convert it into a timestamp in put on the database.

Comment: @Carnal: julianday's not a method it's a standard SQLite function. I think SQLiteDatabase converts ContentValues into string literals when generating SQL query and thus the function is igonered. As proposed in my answer execSQL should be used instead update().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of update() method you should use [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) method which allows you completely control the query syntax. Also instead of calculating fields in query you might consider [creating triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need to enter date like:

Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("DLM", String.format("%1$te-%1$tB-%1$tY",cal));//this will insert date with format 2 July 2011
```

For updating values like fieldValue*2,

you need to fetch the older values from table and then you need to pass it like:

```
values.put("field_name",new_field_value);
```